# Unable to push message into ActiveMQ

Tags: java, activemq-classic

I'm successfully pushing message into ActiveMQ from local Eclipse setup. However, the same code does not push message when I try to execute from server as a `cron` job. It does not even throw an exception during code execution.

Java environment - 1.8

Supporting jars used:

- slf4j-api-1.8.0-beta2.jar
- javax.annotation-api-1.2.jar
- javax.jms-api-2.0.1.jar
- management-api-1.1-rev-1.jar
- activemq-core-5.7.0.jar

Code:

```
try {           
    map = getMessageDetails(session,"MessageQueueEmail");
    userName = map.get("userName");
    password = map.get("password");
    hostName = map.get("mqHostName");
    queue = map.get("queueName");
    // Create a ConnectionFactory
    ActiveMQConnectionFactory factory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(userName, password, hostName);
    // Create a Connection
    connection = factory.createConnection();
    // start the Connection
    connection.start();
    System.out.println("MQ started connection");
    // Create a Session
    sessionMQ = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

    // Create the destination Queue
    Destination destination = sessionMQ.createQueue(queue);

    // Create a MessageProducer from the Session to the Queue
    messageProducer = sessionMQ.createProducer(destination);
    messageProducer.setDeliveryMode(DeliveryMode.NON_PERSISTENT);

    // Create a message
    Message message = sessionMQ.createTextMessage(textMsg);
    System.out.println("MQ Message sent successfully");
    // Tell the producer to send the message
    messageProducer.send(message);
} catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.out.println("\n::::::::::::Error occurred sendEmailMessageToIntranet::::::::::::: " + e.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: You should try setting `DeliveryMode.PERSISTENT` so the `send` operation will block until the message is actually sent. Most JMS implementations will send non-persistent messages asynchronously and won't necessarily report exceptions to the caller.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for response. The issue is resolved after importing correct certificate file to the server. Wondering, why MQ attempts failure notification had not logged

Answer (score -1):

Your code looks ok except you might have expiration going. Try with PERSISTENT and most likely is the issues that you are not redirecting stderr in your cronjob ? Make sure you do something like this:

> */1 * * * * /something/send.sh **&>> /something/out.log**

And then check in the morning.